# Django Compressor with S3 URL Heroku

Tags: django, django-storage, django-compressor

I am currently using django compressor and django storages to run my static media off of s3. My files are as follows:

My storage as per the docs is:

```
from django.core.files.storage import get_storage_class
from storages.backends.s3boto import S3BotoStorage

class CachedS3BotoStorage(S3BotoStorage):
    """
    S3 storage backend that saves the files locally, too.
    """
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CachedS3BotoStorage, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.local_storage = get_storage_class(
            "compressor.storage.CompressorFileStorage")()

    def save(self, name, content):
        name = super(CachedS3BotoStorage, self).save(name, content)
        self.local_storage._save(name, content)
        return name
```

my settings are:

```
# S3 Storage Section
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.environ['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID']
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = os.environ['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = os.environ['AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME']
# AWS_S3_SECURE_URLS = False #turns off https for static files (necessary)

# Used to make sure that only changed files are uploaded with collectstatic
AWS_PRELOAD_METADATA = True

# Django compressor settings
STATICFILES_FINDERS += (
                        'compressor.finders.CompressorFinder',
                        )
COMPRESS_ENABLED = True
COMPRESS_OFFLINE = True
COMPRESS_URL = STATIC_URL
COMPRESS_ROOT = STATIC_ROOT
COMPRESS_STORAGE = 'erp.storage.CachedS3BotoStorage'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'erp.storage.CachedS3BotoStorage'
AWS_LOCATION = 'static'
AWS_QUERYSTRING_EXPIRE = 7200

COMPRESS_JS_FILTERS = [
    'compressor.filters.template.TemplateFilter',
]
```

There is a lot of media to compress which is why I have opted to use offline compression and run the manage.py compress command rather than run collectstatic on dyno restarts as it is just to slow.

Django compressor provides me with a querystring which is great however it contains html which does not load. i.e.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="site-url/static/CACHE/css/da0c0fa8dd51.css?Signature=Signature&amp;Expires=Expires&amp;AWSAccessKeyId=key
```

the two amp; items should not be there. I would rather have it secure but I've also tried AWS_S3_SECURE_URLS = False in the settings which does not seem to change things which makes me think there is something wrong.

I'm using django 1.4 so maybe there is something incompatible.

Comment: It seems that running the compress command doesn't redo the manifest file. So as long as you disable secure urls prior to this it should be alright. I'll try it first and confirm.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I can confirm that if using compress management command you'll need to redo the manifest the file. I did it manually but I'm sure there is a better way. Pretty small problem but I spent a bit of time on this and perhaps it will save someone else some time.

Comment: I don't quite follow. How exactly do you rebuild this manually?

Answer (score 1):

You can use AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH = False in your settings.py to prevent those querystring items