# How to setup django-compressor on heroku, offline compression to S3

Tags: django, heroku, amazon-s3, django-compressor

I followed every QA suggestions found on SO and in different blogs, Everything works ok on my dev machine and nothing works on heroku.

here are my settings:

```
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'arena.utils.MediaRootS3BotoStorage' # media files
# storage

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.environ.get('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID')
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = os.environ.get('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = os.environ.get('AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME')
AWS_PRELOAD_METADATA = True # necessary to fix manage.py collectstatic command to only upload changed files instead of all files

S3_URL = 'https://%s.s3.amazonaws.com' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME
MEDIA_URL = S3_URL + '/media/'

STATIC_URL = S3_URL + '/static/'

ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = STATIC_URL + 'admin/'


COMPRESS_URL = STATIC_URL
COMPRESS_OFFLINE = True
COMPRESS_STORAGE = 'utils.CachedS3BotoStorage'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = COMPRESS_STORAGE
```

When i run collectstatic/compress everything is ok, i see the files being collected to S3 and put in proper places. I see the manifest file.

Loading any page with compressor tag, show an error `OfflineGenerationError: You have offline compression enabled but key "d2a53169c44dec41ce3ee7da19b2b9d4" is missing from offline manifest.` Running `python manage.py compress` again solves nothing. when i check the manifest file, indeed the key it looks for doesn't exist.

What is going wrong here?

Question i already checked:

[How to configure django-compressor and django-staticfiles with Amazon's S3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7698406/how-to-configure-django-compressor-and-django-staticfiles-with-amazons-s3)

[Django Compressor with S3 URL Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10929418/django-compressor-with-s3-url-heroku)

[Configuring django-compressor with remote storage (django-storage - amazon s3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10316131/configuring-django-compressor-with-remote-storage-django-storage-amazon-s3)

Comment: I think this has something to do with how you add less files to your template. I added them dynamically in development, which was fine. When you use the `manage.py compress` command, it doesn't see the dynamically added ones, and cannot compress those.

Comment: @JacobValenta i dont have less files in templates. i have a compiler working automatically on every save in Pycharm. `manage.py compress` works on heroku, doesn't throw any errors, but when i try to load a page i get same error every time. As if it cant read the manifest or something

Answer (score 1):

On my side I have very similar config, and I'm successfully using compressor for more than 2 years.

**settings.py**

```
COMPRESS_STORAGE = 'MyAwesomeApp.app.CachedS3BotoStorage.CachedS3BotoStorage'

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = '#######'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = '########################+#########+BqoQ'
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'myAmazonS3cdn.myawesomewebsite.com'
AWS_S3_SECURE_URLS = False
AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH = False

COMPRESS_ROOT = 'MyAwesomeApp/static'
STATIC_ROOT = 'MyAwesomeApp/static/javascript'
COMPRESS_OUTPUT_DIR = 'compressed'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = COMPRESS_STORAGE

STATIC_URL = "http://myAmazonS3cdn.myawesomewebsite.com/"
COMPRESS_URL = STATIC_URL
COMPRESS_ENABLED = True
```

**CachedS3BotoStorage.py**

```
from django.core.files.storage import get_storage_class
from storages.backends.s3boto import S3BotoStorage

from django.core.files.base import File

class CachedS3BotoStorage(S3BotoStorage):
    """
    S3 storage backend that saves the files locally, too.
    """
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CachedS3BotoStorage, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.local_storage = get_storage_class("compressor.storage.CompressorFileStorage")()

    def save(self, name, content):
        name = super(CachedS3BotoStorage, self).save(name, content)
        self.local_storage._save(name, content)
        return name
```

I'm running **python managep.py compress** locally, and having manifest generated on my static files directory. Heroku only deals with the collecstatic and delivers the most recent manifest version to my cdn.

Regards,

Comment: I had an issue, and adding `AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH = False` is finally making it work. Since the signature changes over time otherwise.

Comment: It is not well documented, but before using the AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH paramenter I was stucked on "Request has expired" error.

Comment: Yes, what I did previously was `AWS_QUERYSTRING_EXPIRE = 63115200`. That sets the request expiration to 2 years from now. But even that's not the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

I completed the above solution with some lines, to fix the problem that create many (multiples) manifest_%.json in Amazon S3

in setting.py:

```
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'your_package.s3utils.CachedS3BotoStorage'
```

in s3utils.py:

```
from storages.backends.s3boto import S3BotoStorage
from django.core.files.storage import get_storage_class

class CachedS3BotoStorage(S3BotoStorage):
    """
    S3 storage backend that saves the files locally, too.
    """
    location = 'static'

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CachedS3BotoStorage, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.local_storage = get_storage_class(
            "compressor.storage.CompressorFileStorage")()

    def url(self, name):
        """
        Fix problem images admin Django S3 images
        """
        url = super(CachedS3BotoStorage, self).url(name)
        if name.endswith('/') and not url.endswith('/'):
            url += '/'
        return url

    def save(self, name, content):
        name = super(CachedS3BotoStorage, self).save(name, content)
        self.local_storage._save(name, content)
        return name

    # HERE is secret to dont generating multiple manifest.json and to delete manifest.json in Amazon S3
    def get_available_name(self, name):
        if self.exists(name):
            self.delete(name)
        return name
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a git repository that contains post_compile hooks to solve this problem. It runs compress after Heroku built the Django app (and also installs `lessc` if you need less in your compressor settings).

https://github.com/nigma/heroku-django-cookbook